# How to send nested SOAP request via SOAPPy (python) or SUDS

Tags: python, soap, siri-xml

I'm trying to generate soap request simliar to this :

I've been able to access the server via soappy , but i didn't find a good example to to pass nest xml parameter to GetStopMonitoringService

I would be if someone can provide some info/like to an example .

thanks .

A sample soap request i need to gerenate via python :

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:acsb="http://www.ifopt.org.uk/acsb" xmlns:datex2="http://datex2.eu/schema/1_0/1_0" xmlns:ifopt="http://www.ifopt.org.uk/ifopt" xmlns:siri="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri" xmlns:siriWS="http://new.webservice.namespace" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="./siri">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header />
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <siriWS:GetStopMonitoringService>
                <Request xsi:type="siri:ServiceRequestStructure">
                    <siri:RequestTimestamp>2012-10-31T09:39:39.480+02:00</siri:RequestTimestamp>
                    <siri:RequestorRef xsi:type="siri:ParticipantRefStructure">KLM12345</siri:RequestorRef>
                    <siri:MessageIdentifier xsi:type="siri:MessageQualifierStructure">0100700:1351669188:4684</siri:MessageIdentifier>
                    <siri:StopMonitoringRequest version="IL2.6" xsi:type="siri:StopMonitoringRequestStructure">
                        <siri:RequestTimestamp>2012-10-31T09:39:39.480+02:00</siri:RequestTimestamp>
                        <siri:MessageIdentifier xsi:type="siri:MessageQualifierStructure">0</siri:MessageIdentifier>
                        <siri:PreviewInterval>PT1H</siri:PreviewInterval>
                        <siri:MonitoringRef xsi:type="siri:MonitoringRefStructure">39795</siri:MonitoringRef>
                        <siri:MaximumStopVisits>100</siri:MaximumStopVisits>
                    </siri:StopMonitoringRequest>
                </Request>
            </siriWS:GetStopMonitoringService>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I use this python code :

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    from  SOAPpy  import SOAPProxy
    import httplib
    httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
    soapaction='http://siri.motrealtime.co.il:8081/Siri/SiriServices/GetStopMonitoringService'
    namespace='http://www.ifopt.org.uk/ifopt'
    server = SOAPProxy('http://siri.motrealtime.co.il:8081/Siri/SiriServices',soapaction=soapaction,namespace=namespace)
    Request =  { 
    'RequestTimestamp':"2014-02-04T09:39:39.480+02:00",
    'RequestorRef':"AG566778",
    'MessageIdentifier':"0100700:1351669188:4684",
    'StopMonitoringRequest': 
        {'version':"IL2.6",
        'RequestTimestamp' :"2014-02-04T09:39:39.480+02:00",
        'MessageIdentifier':0,
        'PreviewInterval':"PT1H",
        'MonitoringRefStructure':21705,
        'MaximumStopVisits':100}
    }

    server.soapproxy.config.dumpSOAPOut = 1     
    server.soapproxy.config.dumpSOAPIn = 1
    print  server.GetStopMonitoringService(Request = Request)
```

but it still doesn't work

Comment: The whole point to SOAP is NOT having to manually work with the xml.  You want to use object notation to read/write requests and responses.  See my post below for a more direct answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I read the source code to figure this out.  I recommend doing the same when you are stuck!

The essential answer to your question (for SOAPpy) is that you need to use a "structType" in order to create a nesting.  Here's an example code snippet where I add a soap header, and in that header I've nested a "SessionHeader" node, and within that a "sessionId" node.

```
from SOAPpy import WSDL, Types as soapTypes
....
soapProxy = server.soapProxy._sa( "urn:sessionid" )
soapHeader = soapTypes.headerType()
soapHeader.SessionHeader = soapTypes.structType( None, "SessionHeader" )
soapHeader.SessionHeader.sessionId = soapTypes.stringType( sessionId )
soapProxy = soapProxy._hd( soapHeader )
server.soapproxy = soapProxy
```

That produces this SOAP (well, the header section of the xml):

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <xsd:SessionHeader SOAP-ENC:root="1">
        <sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">345423534532774</sessionId>
    </xsd:SessionHeader>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

The same kind of thing could be achieved with the soap body.

Note that anywhere you see "SessionHeader" or "sessionid" here, that is an arbitrary customization.  Those could have whatever names you want for your own purposes.